# How can I have multiple backup jobs in Windows Server?

Tags: windows-server-2008, backup

I'm using Windows Server Backup on 2008 server.  Is it possible to have multiple backup jobs from within that program?  I would like to schedule a full backup on Friday and an incremental backup the Monday - Thursday.  Is this possible using WSB?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using the command line/scheduled tasks.  Not sure about using the GUI (I don't use it, myself, command line is easier to make sure it is consistent/what you expected).

Reference: http://blogs.technet.com/b/filecab/archive/2009/04/13/customizing-windows-server-backup-schedule.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simple batch file that copies the daily backup once a week (Friday in my case), And added it to the task scheduler to run once a week. You can create a different backup (Daily/Weekly/Monthly) to suit your needs.
Example of my batch file :

```
rd f:\weekly_friday
robocopy /e f:\windowsimagebackup f:\weekly_friday\
```